# LinqToExcel blank rows

Tags: linq-to-excel

I am using LinqToExcel to easily import Excel data into SQL Server.

```
        var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFileLocation"];
        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);
        var employees = excel.Worksheet<Employee>().ToList();
```

Everything's fine, there is only 1 problem, the fields mapped exactly to the database table fields, and in the database they are NOT NULL.

[image: Input excel file]

Having said that, if you look at this screenshot of Excel file, some rows below row 3 are actually not empty. There are no spaces, but somehow LinqToExcel reads them as well and of course I get exception thrown by EntityFramework saying the field cannot be null.

I need to select all the blank rows below 3 up to 8980 something, and delete them.
Only then I can use LinqToExcel not trying to import blank rows.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a condition to the LINQ statement so the empty rows are not included.

```
var employees = excel.Worksheet<Employee>().Where(x => x.VS2012 != null).ToList();
```

And if checking for not null does not work, then you can check for an empty string

```
var employees = excel.Worksheet<Employee>().Where(x => x.VS2012 != "").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, sure, totally forgot about linq predicate :)

Answer (score 1):

> *but somehow LinqToExcel reads them as well*

This is a quirk of Excel. It remembers how many rows and columns where used when the Sheet was at it largest size. You can see this by typing Ctrl-End. This will select the cell in the last row and column ever used.

Office support describes how to reset the last cell: [Locate and reset the last cell on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Locate-and-reset-the-last-cell-on-a-worksheet-c9e468a8-0fc3-4f69-8038-b3c1d86e99e9)

Basically, you delete excess rows and columns, clear formatting, save the workbook and reopen it.

This work-around could be useful if you have Excel-files waiting to be imported and no time to deploy your fixed Linq2Excel client.